CNN Tutorial Models refusing to train at all
The issue I am having pertains to creating and using CNN models on some well known datasets. The problem began with one of my homework assignments where we were supposed to create a CNN and run it on the CIFAR10 dataset. However this problem seems to go deeper and I suspect there may be something going very wrong.
I noticed that when running my own model that the performance was consistent with random guessing no matter what model I made or what hyperparameters I tuned.
In order to get a better idea of what a good model looks like I downloaded a few tutorials online both on CIFAR10 as well as MNIST. These models on the tutorial pages, website etc. all reported decent accuracy ranging from 60-80%.
Here is where things get weird however. When I run those exact same models (I downloaded the files so no copy/pasting errors) with the same data preprocessing etc. I get the same result as for my own model, no learning happens and the accuracy stays at 10%. This behavior was consistent over at least four different tutorial examples I found online.
I tried creating a new conda environment so I could do a fresh install of tensorflow-gpu, and ensured I was using the same version as the tutorial when possible but still, for whatever reason it seems like the models just refuse to train for me. Below is a minimal reproducible example which I've simply copy/pasted from the CNN Tutorial example on tensorflow.org and my results.
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0


model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))


model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam', 
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))


Results
1563/1563 [==============================] - 250s 11ms/step - loss: 2.3027 - accuracy: 0.0977 -       val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 2/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3028 - accuracy: 0.0999 -     val_loss: 2.3027 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 3/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3027 - accuracy: 0.1011 -   val_loss: 2.3027 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 4/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3028 - accuracy: 0.0993 -    val_loss: 2.3027 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 5/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3027 - accuracy: 0.0957 -   val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 6/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3028 - accuracy: 0.0979 -     val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 7/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 2.3027 - accuracy: 0.0997 -   val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.1000


What is your TF/python version? I tested your code on google colab with TF 2.15.0 and it ran as expected, with rising accuracy (79% train, 71% test after 10 epochs). The behaviour in your question is strange indeed.
